# How to create a normal HTML Table filled in with Database Data using php?

Tags: php, sql, html

Hi im new to frontend world and i made a small sql database filled with some data , i could get the data from database to my php code as Associative Array but the problem is that i cant fill them inside my table , they appear upper and outside the table. with any help i'll be thankful.

```
<?php
include("page.html");
include("databaseConnection.php");

$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, userName from passwords");
$sth->execute();

$result[] = $sth->fetchAll();

if(isset($_POST["showData"])){

echo "<table style='border: 2px solid black'>
<tr>
<th style='border: 1px solid red'>ID</th>
<th style='border: 1px solid black'>User Name</th>
</tr> <tbody>";

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".print_r($value1['ID'])."</td>
        <td>".print_r($value1['userName'])."</td>
        </tr>";
    }

}
echo "</tbody></table>";


}
?>
```

[enter image description of the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypz4f.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using print_r inside a string concatenation.

```
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>".print_r($value1['ID'])."</td>
    <td>".print_r($value1['userName'])."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Remove the print_r statements and the values will show up inside the table.

Comment: thx alot i removed one foreach aswell and the print_r it Works! , have a nice day Sir!.

Answer (score 0):

A quick&dirty solution,not tested :-

```
<?php
include("page.html");
include("databaseConnection.php");

$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, userName from passwords");
$sth->execute();

$result[] = $sth->fetchAll();

if(isset($_POST["showData"])){

echo "<table style='border: 2px solid black'>
<tr>
<th style='border: 1px solid red'>ID</th>
<th style='border: 1px solid black'>User Name</th>
</tr> <tbody>";
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $value1['ID']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $value1['userName']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }

}
echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: sorry...but i am new to stackoverflow community...ok i will delete this answer (comment)

Comment: @Krysan sure i'll :)

Comment: @SamBoHamdan well I am also a beginner in PHP,but I had solved this problem when I was learning PHP...

Comment: nice i hope that u can help me 2 @Krysan , u can find the pic in the Question

Comment: @SamBoHamdan please check if this helps...it's a really old piece of code

Comment: @Krysan lol good idea tho but didnt displayed any result it made an empty Table xD.

Comment: @Krysan there is no error at all i've tryed many ways with ur idea but it didnt displayed any data in the Table , maybe cuz the extension of the file is php .

Comment: @SamBoHamdan You should try replacing "echo" with print_r...maybe it will make it work

Answer (score 0):

Your tbody tag should be parent of all your tr elements and your header in thead. Check this struct bellow:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: thx for answer i've tryed this but also didnt work the result always appears outside the table